# python3.5.1 can not parse json data from url

Tags: python, json

I have already got my url and access this url on the browser. It will give you json data format, however, when I use build-in function of python3 it also gives me an error and the `get_report` gives me `<function get_report at 0x103362840>`. How could I use build-in function of python3 to return the json data?

Here is my code

```
  def get_report(report,api_key):
     uri = urllib.parse.urljoin(API_ENDPOINT, report)
     uri += "?api_key = %s" % API_KEY

     request = urllib.request.Request(uri)
     response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
     data = response.read().decode('utf-8')
     print (data)
   return data
try:
    data = get_report("azure_cost", API_KEY)
```

Comment: When you say it gives you an error, please give us the actual error returned. It'll be easier to clarify the problem and threat it.

Answer (score 2):

Before anything else, please, when you put raw code on the page, use the {} button, or put 4 spaces before each line of your code. It helps clarifying the overall.

If you receive a string containing formatted and valid JSON, you can parse it using the builtin `json` module.

A simple code snippet that can be used to parse a json string using this module can be that:

```
to_parse = "{'foo': 'bar', 'test': 'result'}"

from json import loads
parsed = loads(to_parse)
print(parsed['foo']) # will print "bar", the value stored below the 'foo' key.
```

It will store the loaded list/dictionary in a variable, that you'll be able to use later.

EDIT:

By looking at your recent update, I must precise that, if you didn't know yet, if you try to print something and it gives you this result:

```
<function "any_function" at 0x103362840>
```

It means that the thing you just printed is a function, actually stored on the address `0x103362840` in memory (you don't have to worry about this part), which means you can actually call this function using this syntax (following the example just a bit higher):

```
>>> variable.any_function()  # Notice the add of the (), which means it will be considered and called as a function, and not a variable.
```

Now, if you try to do something like:

```
>>> print(variable.any_function())
```

instead of:

```
>>> print(variable.any_function)
```

you will print the result that the function returned. So here, it will execute the function get_report, then return the result, and since we are printing the result in the console, if the get_report returns the actual needed content, it will print it in the console.